# Expectation for a $\chi^2_n$ distributed random variable.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, descriptive-statistics

Consider $X_1,\ldots, X_n\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ iid, where $\mu$, $\sigma^2$ are unknown and  $c>0$.  Define

$$S_n^2:=\sum_{k=1}^n\Big(X_k-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\Big)^2$$

Now I want to calculate

$$E[cS_n^2-\sigma^2]$$
Actually I was reading that $S_n^2$ might be $\chi_n^2$-distributed, but I do not know why. So does someone has a hint on this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any source explaining the Bonferroni correction will prove $ES_n^2=(n-1)\sigma^2$, which is enough for your purposes.

Comment: I was able to show it by simple calculation. Thanks for your comment!